# Pdf blob url in <embed> is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

I am working on a angularjs application. In one of the page, I need to display a pdf.
so, this is what i tried.

in controller:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3030/getpdf/1234', {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
    });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $scope.src = objectUrl;
    $('.pdfembed').html('<embed src="' + $scope.src + '" type="application/pdf" width="60%" height="600px"></embed>');
});
```

in partial template:

```
<div class="pdfembed"></div>
```

This method is working in Chrome, Firefox. But not in IE.

I am not sure whether the problem in IE or Adobe reader. So confused.

Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of IE? Notably, `Blob` is only supported from IE11/Edge: http://caniuse.com/#search=blob

Comment: Thanks, I am using IE11. still I couldnt figure it out, why it is not working.

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I really need solution for this issue.